# GTK+ Theme not found

Tags: qt, gtk, raspberry-pi

I am developing a Qt4 gui on raspberry pi 2. When trying to run the interface I get an error that says QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ Theme. I have looked and looked but can not find a solution to this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the contents of your `/usr/share/themes`?

Comment: Adwaita Clearlooks-3.4 Emacs Natura PiX ThinIce                      Artxiz.boxed  Clearlooks-Olive Industrial Onyx Raleigh                         Bear2 Crux Mikachu Onyx-Citrus Redmond                                    Clearlooks Default Mist Orang Syscrash